# Statements about the doctrine or the future made by current LDS Prophet, and the church view on those

Tags: lds, inspiration, infallibility, foreknowledge

I was looking at this [mormon.org page](https://www.mormon.org/faq/present-day-prophet) that mentions that "The current prophet and President of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is Thomas S. Monson."

1. Does the LDS church assert that doctrinal statements made by the
   current Prophet are either "inspired", "infallible", or both?
2. Has the Prophet made any statements about (near)future events that
   Mormons expect to happen?

(I am separating "inspired" and "infallible" because I am not sure how they are interpreted in this context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does the LDS church assert that doctrinal statements made by the current Prophet are either "inspired", "infallible", or both?

Inspired, definitely, but not infallible. Prophets are merely mortal men.

> 2. Has the Prophet made any statements about (near)future events that Mormons expect to happen?

Yes, actually. Just a couple months ago, [President Monson announced](http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/four-new-temples-announced-president-monson) that four new temples would be built in the near future, and named the cities they will be built in.

Comment: he he, I like that answer to my question about the future. I take that there has not been statements about things that are purely outside of the church's control...

Comment: @x457812 Nope, as far as I know, nothing of that sort.

Comment: cool, thanks, although now I started to ponder on how it might be possible to be "inspired" but yet not "infallible". Wouldn't an inspired doctrinal statement (or an inspired statement about the future) always be infallible?

Comment: @x457812 LDS teachers don't tend to refer to *statements* as infallible, though. The *doctrine* certainly is. The leadership and love and Atonement of *Christ* certainly is, but statements by church leaders are not said anywhere that I can find, to be infallible.

Comment: Also, to expand on the second point of my answer. New temples are announced like I showed, but in a way, these are very much prophecies as well. [Temple sites are not always easy to secure after they are directed to be built](https://speeches.byu.edu/talks/dean-m-davies_god-will-use-you-god-will-bless-you/) (read that account of the Philadelphia temple).